# Case Insensitive Dictionary with char key in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

If I have a `Dictionary<char,...>` is it possible to make method ContainsKey case-insensitive?

I know, in `Dictionary<string,...>` is used StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, but what to do when key in dictionary is char-type?

Comment: A *very* simple option would be to add the same value for 'a' and 'A', for example. But consider that as a workaround.

Comment: Reference for your 'I Know ..' : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988643/case-insensitive-dictionary-with-string-key-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: To make it clear - are you looking for a solution for a case-insensitive dictionary (so `myDict['a']` is equivalent to `myDict['A']`), or *only* a case-insensitive ContainsKey method (so `myDict.ContainsKey('a')` returns true regardless of whether 'a' or 'A', or both, are defined?)

Comment: @MickyDuncan Indeed, which is why I did not post it as an aswer. However, it is simple and easy to implement. And after all, it would only take up 26 more spots *if* they are all used - not that much!

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan I have dictionary with only uppercase letters but when I use ContainsKey('a') it must work.

Comment: And if you use `myDict['a']` to retrieve the value, do you need that to work as well?

Comment: @MickyDuncan Well, only a-z have uppercases, right? ^^

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan Yes, but what I need is to have dictionary with only uppercase letters (efficient memory). With ContainsKey method sometimes I try to check lowercase and sometimes uppercase letter.

Comment: @DionV. No I misread question, I thought it was Dictionary<`string`>. :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class has a constructor that takes any `IEqualityComparer`. What you need to do is implement a simple case-insensitive `IEqualityComparer<char>` and pass it to the constructor, and it will be used when evaluating the key.

This is a similar question for implementing `IComparer<char>` without case sensitivity. `IEqualityComparer` will be practically identical:

- [What is the correct way to compare char ignoring case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394877/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-char-ignoring-case)

Comment: It will make ContainsKey case-insensitive (like OP wants) or whole dictionary?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't consider the possibility that the OP wants *only* ContainsKey to be insensitive. It seems like a strange requirement.

Comment: Looks like OP wants to add both 'x' and 'X' but he wants single operation to check if any of these entries exist

Comment: Let's see what the OP has to say.

Comment: I have dictionary with only uppercase letters (efficient memory) but with ContainsKey method sometimes I try to check lowercase and sometimes uppercase.

Answer (score 8):

You can implement your own comparer:

```
public class CharComparer : IEqualityComparer<char>
{
     public bool Equals(char c1, char c2)
     {
          return char.ToLowerInvariant(c1) == char.ToLowerInvariant(c2);
     }
     public int GetHashCode(char c1)
     {
          return char.ToLowerInvariant(c1).GetHashCode();
     }

}
```

And pass it to the constructor:

```
var dict = new Dictioanry<char, object>(new CharComparer());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a extension method aswell:

```
public static bool ContainsKeyInsensitive(this Dictionary<char, ...> dict, char c)
{      
  return dict.ContainsKey(char.ToUpper(c)) || dict.ContainsKey(char.ToLower(c));
}
```

Comment: This would pretty much negate any advantage a dictionary has in O(1) lookups, transforming them into O(n). This is not a good solution.

Comment: The only correct answer here. But implementation is not the best. Just do two lookups for upper and lower char instead of checking all keys

Comment: derape: no, a Dictionary uses a hashtable for efficient lookups: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730620/how-does-a-hash-table-work

Comment: @Sergey I believe two lookups are not even neccessary when using `char`. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You could also call it twice.

```
if (dict.ContainsKey(char.ToLowerInvariant(ch)) || dict.ContainsKey(char.ToUpperInvariant(ch)))
{
    ...
}
```

As an extension method, this becomes:

```
public static bool ContainsKeyInsensitive<T>(this Dictionary<char, T> dict, char ch)
{
    return dict.ContainsKey(char.ToLowerInvariant(ch)) || dictionary.ContainsKey(char.ToUpperInvariant(ch));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first; I know the accepted answer works and it is a good answer. Yet, I found out that it is not neccessary to implement any extension method/additional logic to achieve the desired result.

I suppose you are using a dictionary because you want to map a key to a specific value - which is exactly what they are for. If you use it only to look up keys, you should be using a `HashSet<char>`.

Alright, that being said, let's take a look at the three options you have with `char`;

- You are willing to map uppercase **as well** as lowercase, giving both uppercase and lowercase a *different* value.
- You are willing to map **only** lowercase, meaning uppercase has *the same* value as uppercase.
- You are willing to map **only** uppercase, meaning lowercase has *the same* value as uppercase.

I'll explain them all three. For all options, consider not knowing whether the input char is uppercase or lowercase.

**Option 1; Different keys, different values.**

Mapping both is the way to go here. If you need a different value for `'a'` and `'A'`, *you need to add them both anyway*. Therefore, you can just use `.ContainsKey()` and it will return the desired result. This option probably doesn't fit your needs, since you are looking for a case insensitive dictionary.

**Option 2: Lowercase has the same value as uppercase.**

If you are wanting to get the lowercase value *anytime*, just call `.ContainsKey(yourChar.ToLower())`.

**Option 3: Uppercase has the same value as lowercase.**

Same story! Only now, use `.ContainsKey(yourChar.ToUpper())` to get the correct results. Since you posted in your comment that your dictionary has uppercased chars only, this should be the way to go.

The same goes for a case insensitive `Dictionary<string,T>`; just only map either lower or uppercase (lowercase has my preference, but that's your own choice).

The following code snippet should demonstrate how it works.

```
Dictionary<char, object> dic = new Dictionary<char, object>();

public object GetIfKeyExists(char c)
{
    // Consider c = 'a' or c = 'A'

    // Option 1: Both have different values, so they should be existing anyway.
    if (dic.ContainsKey(c)) return dic[c];

    // Option 2: Only lowercase is mapped.
    char correctInput = c.ToLower();
    if (dic.ContainsKey(correctInput)) return dic[correctInput];

    // Option 3: Only uppercase is mapped.
    char correctInput = c.ToUpper();
    if (dic.ContainsKey(correctInput)) return dic[correctInput];
}
```

Then, finally, I still wonder why you would check for upper *or* lower. What information does it give if it returns true? You still don't know *which* exactly exists - and that's why you should choose to either map upper or lowercase and stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

just define the Dictionary like that :

```
Dictionary<string, int> Dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```