# read a text file and search for string in memory efficient way (and abort when found)

Tags: c#, string, file, text, system.io.file

I'm searching for a string in a text file (also includes XML). This is what I thought first:

```
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
{
    string s = String.Empty;
    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (s.Contains("mySpecialString"))
            return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

I want to read line by line to minimize the amount of RAM used. When the string has been found it should abort the operation. The reason why I don't process it as XML is because it has to be parsed and would also consume more memory as necessary.

Another easy implementation would be

```
bool found = File.ReadAllText(path).Contains("mySpecialString") ? true : false;
```

but that would read the complete file into memory, which isn't what I want. On the other side it could have a performance increase.

Another one would be this

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path))
{
    if (line.Contains("mySpecialString"))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

But which one of them (or another one from you?) is more memory efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a query with [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx), so it only reads as many lines as it needs to, in order to satisfy your query. The `Any()` method will stop when it hits a line containing your string.

```
return File.ReadLines(fileName).Any(line => line.Contains("mySpecialString"));
```

Comment: Wow. That solution looks nice and simple!

Answer (score 2):

I also prefer the accepted answer. Maybe i'm micro opimizing things here but you have asked for a memory efficient approach. Also consider that the text you are searching could also contain  new-line characters like `'\r'`, `'\n'` or `"\r\n"` and a large file could theoretically contain a single line which negates the benefit of `ReadLines`.

So you *could* use this method:

```
public static bool FileContainsString(string path, string str, bool caseSensitive = true)
{
     if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return false;

    using (var stream = new StreamReader(path))
    while (!stream.EndOfStream)
    {
        bool stringFound = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            char strChar = caseSensitive ? str[i] : Char.ToUpperInvariant(str[i]);
            char fileChar = caseSensitive ? (char)stream.Read() : Char.ToUpperInvariant((char)stream.Read());
            if (strChar != fileChar)
            {
                stringFound = false;
                break; // break for-loop, start again with first character at next position
            }
        }
        if (stringFound) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```
bool containsString = FileContainsString(path, "mySpecialString", false); // ignore case if desired
```

Note that this might be the most efficient approach and hidden in a method also readable. But it has one drawback, it's not feasible to implement a culture-sensitive comparison because it looks at single characters and not at substrings.

So you have to keep some edge cases in mind where you can run into issues, like    the [famous turkish i example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994325.aspx#cltsafcode_topic4) or [surrogate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394898/284240).

Comment: Thanks for your addition. Can you elaborate the last point a little bit more? For which cases does it work and for which not?

Comment: @testing: for example the famous [turkish `i` example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms994325.aspx#cltsafcode_topic4). Or [surrogate pairs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8k5611at%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which consist of two characters.

Comment: But that are edge cases,  in mosts cases it's not an issue. You just have to keep it in mind.

Comment: there is an unobvious flaw here! a little difficult to explain but if it matches only the first few chars and breaks out, but a match is right after it gets skipped over. make any sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think both of your solutions are the same. Read at the MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

There it says: "The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned"

The same article also suggests that ReadLines should be used in conjunction with LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Which *both* solution do you mean? I also read about `ReadAllLines`, but I didn't used it in my examples. So `ReadLines` seems the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Ah yes, I jumped over it. ReadLines should be the same as the first solution with ReadLine. ReadAllLines is less efficient because it reads the complete file.