# Find character occurrences ignoring letter case c#

Tags: c#, linq, char, letter

I have a function, that returns a number of character occurrences at text. But there is a problem: letter case matters. 
Function:

```
public static int GetOccurrences(String text, Char character)
    {
        return text.Count(x => x == character);
    }
```

For "*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, pro eu erant semper ancillae*" it will be 1 "L" and 3 "l", for example. Is it possible to ignore letter case?

Comment: Just make a lower case copy of the string, do your comparison, and return the int.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to compare char ignoring case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394877/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-char-ignoring-case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply put them all to upper case when you compare them

```
text.Count(x => char.ToUpperInvariant(x) == char.ToUpperInvariant(character))
```

Comment: Check Jon's answer to this post regarding case sensitivity when doing comparisons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case

Comment: @RufusL That's very interesting, I didn't know about that. Would specifying the `CultureInfo` be better?

Comment: He answered a duplicate of this question here, which describes it better than I could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394877/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-char-ignoring-case

Comment: @CNuts Sorry, meant to add the comment on the OP's post, was on a phone at the time