# Case insensitive comparing of chars in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know a method to make case-insensitive comparing of two char symbols? I don't want to use `.ToUpper()` or `To.Lower()`, I want to compare them like strings `String.Compare("abc", "ABC", CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: Maybe use `.ToString()` and here you go?

Comment: Why you don't want to use `ToUpper`?

Comment: See [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394898/7831383) to this (maybe duplicate) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394877/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-char-ignoring-case)

Comment: @Rafalon:  already closed because of that duplicate ;-)

Comment: Thank you, I've got all the information from the link of duplicated question. I can use ToUpper, I just want to know if it is possible or not to use CompareOptions while I'm comparing symbols.

Comment: @TimSchmelter aye right, I didn't refresh the page. @AliakseiFutryn if you'd read the entire answer, you'd see there's a variant with `.ToString()` that uses `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes, I see, thank you.