# How to sort an array of chars alphabetically so that the uppercase and the lowercase version of the same letter are next to each other?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

For example

Input array: 'a', 'b', 'B', 'A'

Output with Array.Sort(): 'A', 'B', 'a', 'b'

Desired output: 'A', 'a', 'B', 'b'

I understand why 'A' is considered lower than 'a', but I want it to be sorted alphabetically, not by the corresponding integers of the characters.

Is there a Comparer class that would solve the problem as a second argument for Array.Sort() ?

Comment: Are they `char` elements, or single character strings?

Comment: They are char elements, declared like so:

char [] charArray = {  'a', 'b', 'B', 'A' };

Comment: The question is slightly underspecified. Plainly you want `A` and `a` to be both less than `B` and `b` but it is unclear if `a` is smaller than, greater than or equal to `A` in your conception.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a Comparer class that would solve the problem as a second argument for Array.Sort() ?

For strings, you want to use OrdinalIgnoreCase or InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, depending on whether you care about culture sensitivity or not. See:

[Which is generally best to use -- StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase or StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696/)

For chars, I do not know of a built-in comparer that does that, but it is easy to write your own. See

[What is the correct way to compare char ignoring case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394877/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-char-ignoring-case)

Note that `Array.Sort` is a mutating sort; if you want a non-mutating sort, then do an `OrderBy` on `ToUpper` or `ToUpperInvariant`.  Note that there are pitfalls here; see

[How to sort an array of chars alphabetically so that the uppercase and the lowercase version of the same letter are next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635264/)

Note also that it is unclear whether your intention is that `A` and `a` be *equal* -- in which case `A`, `a`, `A` would be a legal ordering, since equal things are equal, or whether you still want an ordering within `a` and `A`.  Again, be careful. If that's what you want then you'll have to do a `ThenBy` also.

Comment: A few years late, but did you mean to link back to the question you are answering?

Comment: @NetMage: Hah! Uh, obviously not, but I have no memory of what article I did intend to link to. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to create a new `char` `Array` with the right order:

```
var ans = chars.OrderBy(Char.ToUpper).ThenBy(c => c).ToArray();
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing `c.ToString().ToUpper()` which allocates a new string, and not `char.ToUpper(c)`, which does not?

Comment: I note also that you can eliminate the first lambda entirely: `chars.OrderBy(char.ToUpper)...`

Comment: @EricLippert I forgot about `Char.ToUpper` - it seems like legacy code to me, I expect everything to be a method / extension method fluent style. Updated my answer.